# how to assign QmlListProperty of singleton type

Tags: qt, qml, qqmllistproperty

I have `MyType` registered as `qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyType>("org.examples", 1, 0, "MyType")` which has `QmlListProperty<MyListElement>` - `myList`. 
What syntax i should use at QML side to assign something to `MyType.myList`?

Seems like that is incorrect:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
  MyType.myList = [
    MyListElement {
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the MyListElement object using javascript and then add it to the list with push since QmlListProperty is translated to a list in QML.

In this case with [`Qt.createQmlObject()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method), so assuming MyListElement was created with:

```cpp
qmlRegisterType<MyListElement>("org.examples", 1, 0, "MyListElement");
```

So the solution is:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    var o = Qt.createQmlObject('import org.examples 1.0; MyListElement {}', this)
    // o.foo_property = foo_value;
    MyType.myList.push(o);
}
```

Comment: It works, but  that syntax is terrible. When using Qt.createQmlObject or Qt.createComponent there is no access to objects added to list by their id's